# NUnit test under mono

Tags: unit-testing, mono, nunit

I have a mut.cs as follows.

```
using System;

namespace ns
{
    public class Arith {
        public int Add(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
        public int Mul(int x, int y) {
            return x * y;
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with a Unit test for this - mut_test.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using ns;

namespace Unit.Tests {
    [TestFixture]
    public class ArithTests {
        private Arith m_arith = null;
        [Setup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            m_arith = new Arith();
        }
        [Test]
        public void ValidateAdd()
        {
            int res = m_arith.Add(10,10);
            Assert.AreEqual(20, res);
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            m_arith = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the following command.

```
gmcs -debug -t:library -r:System -r:$NUNITLIB -out:mut.dll mut_test.cs mut.cs
```

But I get the following error. $NUNITLIB is aliased as $NUNITLIB=$NUNITBIN/framework/nunit.framework.dll

```
mut_test.cs(9,10): error CS0118: `Unit.Tests.ArithTests.Setup()' is a `method' but a `type' was expected
mut_test.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SetupAttribute' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute you're looking for is called SetUp, not Setup.

See here: [NUnit documentation - Setup](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.5.5)

Comment: Yes, it was the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`SetUp` in NUnit has a capital U](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.5.5).

I hate that it's spelled that way (even though it seems to be [correctly spelled](http://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammartips/grammar-tip-setup-set-up.asp) due to being a verb), but that's the source of your problem.