# Issues with running nunit-console.exe with Mono

Tags: mono, nunit, nunit-console

I could make a dll for NUnit [NUnit test under mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967726/nunit-test-under-mono), but when I tried to run in with nunit-console.exe I get the following error message.

```
Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 10.3.0.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( 2.6.4 (tarball Thu Apr 22 13:24:33 MDT 2010) )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-2.0

** (/Users/smcho/bin/NUnit-2.5.5.10112/bin/net-2.0/nunit-console.exe:36800): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /private/var/folders/m4/m4u1hmP+FHOQaiZbHj1UCk+++TI/-Tmp-/nunit20/ShadowCopyCache/36800_634111616836311880/Tests_-22323139/assembly/shadow/54274fc2/118e035c_45a94c9e_00000001/mut.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   nunit.framework    (assemblyref_index=1)
     Version:    2.5.5.10112
     Public Key: 96d09a1eb7f44a77
System error: Invalid argument


** (/Users/smcho/bin/NUnit-2.5.5.10112/bin/net-2.0/nunit-console.exe:36800): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.5.10112, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies.
```

What might be wrong? I have nunit.framework.dll under /Users/smcho/bin/NUnit-2.5.5.10112/bin/net-2.0/framework, but it doesn't seem to know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another frustrating point about using NUnit in Mono.  As far as I've been able to tell, you need to have all of those missing files (there will be more than just `nunit.framework.dll`) in the same directory as `nunit-console.exe`.

There might be a command line option either in `mono` or `nunit-console.exe` to specify another directory to search for missing DLLs -- I'm not sure.  Barring that, you'll have to copy the missing DLLs into the same folder as `nunit-console.exe`, or you'll have to `cd` into the `framework` folder and use `mono ../nunit-console.exe /path/to/my/tests.dll`

Comment: Adding the framework directory to $MONO_PATH solved this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @prosseek Thanks for your tip, this solved the problem for me. Copying the DLLs didn't help (I use mac and this probably only works on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Once nuget is installed, you can use it to install nunit.console like so:
(This is from my .circlci/config.yml file)

```
- run: mono --runtime=v4.0 nuget.exe install nunit.console
- run: msbuild MySolution.sln
- run: mono --runtime=v4.0 NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.12.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe FirstModule.Tests/bin/Debug/FirstModule.Tests.dll
- run: mono --runtime=v4.0 NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.12.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe SecondModule.Tests/bin/Debug/SecondModule.Tests.dll
```

The trick is to specify the entire path for the NUnit.ConsoleRunner and to watchout for the `-` changing into a `.` by version 3